# cURL an API in python and return the response as JSON

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm learning Python and try to use it in my class project. I'm looking for a way to curl an API and return the response json. For example, the response after curling an API is JSON and how can I return it also as JSON

```
        response = requests.get("https://github.com/timeline.json")
        response = response.content
```

return response doesn't return it in json while return with jsonify(reponse) get this error (Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable).

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

```
response = requests.get("https://github.com/timeline.json")
response_json = response.json()
print(response_json["message"])
print(response_json["documentation_url"])
```

The method [`json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) returns the json-encoded content of a response as a dict. Additionally, you may want to use the new API at https://api.github.com/events ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-public-events)).

Comment: I did attempt to use .json() earlier, however, some of the character return to it's Unicode form.